# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. though i have chosen a unique identifier, yet the error persist

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

here is my code; I have assigned a unique key, Key={stream.id} which is unique to all the streams created; yet the same error:

```
import React from "react";
import { fetchStreams } from "../../actions";

class StreamList extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchStreams();
  }
  renderList() {
    return this.props.streams.map((stream) => {
      return (
        <div className="item" key={stream.id}>
          {this.renderAdmin(stream)}
          <i className="large middle aligned icon camera" />
          <div className="content">
            {stream.title}
            <div className="description">{stream.description}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Streams</h2>
        <div className="ui celled list">{this.renderList()}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried logging out `stream.id` to check the value is actually what you expect? And, are you sure this is the code causing the issue?

Comment: Does renderAdmin use map?

Comment: renderAdmin doesn't use map

Comment: Logging stream.id renders undefined

Answer (score 2):

If id is not unique or undefined then try using index but I think that and important thing to note if the ids are not unique then thats a problem

Maybe your using mock data and all the ids are the same

```
return this.props.streams.map((stream, index) => {
          return (
            <div className="item" key={stream.id || index}>
              {this.renderAdmin(stream)}
              <i className="large middle aligned icon camera" />
              <div className="content">
                {stream.title}
                <div className="description">{stream.description}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        });
      }
```

Comment: Seems like a good answer, but they might still run into the same issue with this code; if `stream.id` of 1st iteration is `1`, but undefined in 2nd iteration, `index` will be used, which would also be `1`, and warning would be triggered. Edge-case, but still possible. Maybe encourage just using `index` only instead of `stream.id || index`

Comment: Yeah agreed on this :D either make sure the ids are there and uniqe otherwise just use an index or even a genetateUUid() function and pass them as keys :D

Comment: In the case of mock data, what should i do

Comment: Can you paste what the data payload looks like when you console.log(this.props.streams)